# SQL Join producing duplicate rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-order-by

I have the following PostgreSQL statement:

```
SELECT answer, answermark,answerid, answer.questionid, quizid 
FROM answer
LEFT JOIN  questions 
  ON  answermark = answer.questionid 
WHERE quizid = 1
ORDER BY answermark
```

However the result I get back has duplicates of the 3 rows I am
looking for.  How do I change my query in order to eliminate the duplicates.

[image: Query Result]

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I wouldn't use distinct as it hides the problem.  It seems you have a design flaw on the table structure which is causing the cardinality problem of duplicate records; or you're missing join criteria. What are the keys and foreign keys of both these tables?

Answer (score 1):

Using distinct in select statement you can remove duplicates

try this:-

```
SELECT distinct answer, answermark,answerid, answer.questionid, quizid FROM answer
LEFT JOIN  questions ON  answermark = answer.questionid WHERE quizid =1
ORDER BY answermark
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your queries using *qualified* column names.  Every column reference should include the table name.  This is a good habit; it prevents unexpected results such as the ones you are seeing.

Based on the column names, I think your query is:

```
SELECT a.answer, a.answermark, a.answerid, a.questionid, q.quizid 
FROM answer LEFT JOIN 
     questions q
     ON  a.answermark = a.questionid 
---------^ I am guessing `answermark` comes from `answer`, not `questions`.
WHERE q.quizid = 1
ORDER BY a.answermark;
```

I have no idea why a column named `answermark` would be compared to a column called `questionid`, regardless of the source of the tables.  If this is a valid comparison, then you have very poor naming conventions for your database.

I suspect you want something like this:

```
SELECT a.answer, a.answermark, a.answerid, a.questionid, q.quizid 
FROM answer LEFT JOIN 
     questions q
     ON q.questionid = a.questionid 
WHERE q.quizid = 1
ORDER BY a.answermark;
```